# Show subfolders only with Total Commander?

Tags: windows, total-commander, directory-listing

I have a directory that looks like this

```
Folder01 
    Subfolder 1 
        File1 
        File2 
        File3 
    Subfolder 2 
        File1 
        File2 
    Subfolder 3 
        File1 
        File2 
        File3 
Folder02 
    Subfolder 1 
        File1 
        File2 
        File3 
    Subfolder 2 
        File1 
        File2 
    Subfolder 3 
        File1 
        File2 
        File3 
Folder03 
    Subfolder 1 
        File1 
        File2 
        File3 
    Subfolder 2 
        File1 
        File2 
    Subfolder 3 
        File1 
        File2 
        File3
```

I want to show only a list of subfolders only of every parent folders in Total Commander. How can I do this?

Comment: I know of another program that can show you all the folders in one listing. So, it will show Folder01, all its subfolders, and their subfolders, Folder02, all its subfolders, and their subfolders, and so on. And you won't be shown the files (if you want it like that) unless you open any of the folders. Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: I actually want to show only Subfolder 1, Subfolder 2, Subfolder 3 etc... and not Folder01. If the other program has the ability to zip then tell me

Answer (score 0):

In case you have the folders in a root of your drive for instance in C:\ and expected result
in panel within Total commander like this one

```
    "c:\Folder01\Subfolder 1"
    "c:\Folder01\Subfolder 2"
    "c:\Folder01\Subfolder 3"
    "c:\Folder02\Subfolder 1"
    "c:\Folder02\Subfolder 2"
    .
    .
```

but excluded lines like this

```
    "c:\Folder01"
    "c:\Folder02"
    "c:\Folder03"
```

1. go for file find (Alt-F7)
2. put * into the "Search for:" field on tab General
3. use "tc" plugin on the Plugin tab for two conditions
4. "tc", "folder(atribut)", "=", "yes"
5. "tc", "Path", "Reg. exp.", "^(.*\){2}.*$"

number 2 in item 5. represents the count of \ (backslash) in the path

In such a case your folders are deeper add 1 for every level (backslash) within your path